# MySQL - Select WHERE NOT EXITS (code inside)

Tags: mysql, where-clause, exists

can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I want all of sat table and id,cliente,direccion,telefono from clientes INNER JOIN clientes.id = sat.clientid, but I only want these fields if it doesn't exist in the year 2015 and month 02.

Well, in sat table I have assistance tickets, their descriptions... and I want to know which "ids" I've not visited in this month and this year.

**sorry form english, thanks

```
<i> 
SELECT sat.*, clientes.id, clientes.cliente, clientes.direccion, clientes.telefono FROM sat INNER JOIN clientes ON sat.clientid = clientes.id WHERE not exits 
(SELECT sat.*, clientes.cliente 
        FROM sat INNER JOIN clientes ON sat.clientid = clientes.id
        WHERE YEAR(sat.fecha_trabajo)='2015' AND MONTH(sat.fecha_trabajo)='02'
) 

</i>
```

Comment: What does sat.fecha_trabajo look like? Is it a varchar or a date field?

Comment: Is this just a case of a simple typo (`WHERE NOT EXITS` instead of `WHERE NOT EXISTS`)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what "sat" stands for, but here is a guess:

```
SELECT sat.*, clientes.id, clientes.cliente, clientes.direccion, 
clientes.telefono FROM sat INNER JOIN clientes ON sat.clientid = clientes.id 
WHERE not exits 
(SELECT * 
    FROM sat LEFT JOIN clientes ON sat.clientid = clientes.id
    WHERE sat.fecha_trabajo BETWEEN '2015-02-01' AND '2015-02-28'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I were just typing "exists" wrong.

Well but, I've another question. Im executing this in MySQL console and it doesn't work. If y use YEAR(fecha_trabajo)=YEAR('2015-02-01') works well! but the command MONTH doesn't work and I am using it in another section of the website.

ERROR 1064. I've just downloaded XAAMP with latest PHP version.

```
SELECT sat.*, clientes.cliente 
    FROM sat INNER JOIN clientes ON sat.clientid = clientes.id
    WHERE MONTH(fecha_trabajo)= MONTH('2015-02-01')
```